# Overwrite local changes in Git

Tags: git

I am a newbie in Git and it is seems a bit challenging. 
I have made changes in a local directory of my repository. These changes are the deletion of a file and the modification of several. How can I go back to the initial state before this changes happen?(This is the state when the repository was cloned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear all local changes by doing this.

```
git reset --hard
```

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html

Note that it is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use...

```
git checkout .
```

...which will throw away all *dirty* changes.